# Installing NextGIS Connect into QGIS 3?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, nextgis

Just acquired free version of NEXTGIS and trying to install the plugin for QGIS. It tells me it was not designed for version 3 of QGIS.

How do I set up the QGIS-NEXTGIS interface then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NextGIS Connect is not available at the moment for QGIS3. We are waiting for a long term support release of QGIS 3. Meanwhile, you can use Connect on [NextGIS QGIS](http://nextgis.com/nextgis-qgis/) (based on 2.x) or original QGIS 2.x.

**Disclaimer**: I'm a developer at NextGIS.

Comment: When is it anticipated that QGIS3 will have a workable interface?

Comment: We can not pinpoint the exact date because we need: 1. Long term QGS3 release, 2. NextGIS Release based on QGIS 3 sources, 3. NextGIS cloud (nextgis.com) server rendering upgrade to QGIS3 and 4. finally - NextGIS connect release.