# Displaying pie charts in web map created using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, leaflet, chart

I have created a web map to show some sales information using QGIS with Leaflet library.

Is there a way to show pie charts in the same web map as a separate layer?

Although pie charts are visible in the QGIS desktop version, it disappears when it converts to a web map.

I guess there should be a way to edit the HTML file to make pie charts visible.

Answer (score 5):

You don't mention how you create web map. For example using [NextGIS Connect](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/nextgis_connect/) plugin for QGIS 2.18.x you can create such [pie charts](http://inir.nextgis.com/resource/1/display?panel=layers). This is done using nextgis.com cloud web client, based on OpenLayers. But you can do the same using leaflet. See [an example](https://github.com/nextgis/nextgisweb_tinymap) of such integration.

[image]

**Disclaimer**: I'm developer at NextGIS.

Comment: This is great! Isn't this available for QGIS 3.0?

Comment: Not yet. See explanation at this topic: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/297478/9904

Comment: My corporate network blocked the site after I created a new web map using this site. it says there is a security threat :(

Comment: This is subject of your corporate network settings. But you can install NextGIS Web inside your network or any other hosting: http://docs.nextgis.com/docs_ngweb/source/sysadmin.html. This is open source software. Also, we need more details on that. Never had such problem reported before.